# How to create reusable code with dataclasses and airflow dags

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, dbt, python-dataclasses

I'm relatively new to using airflow so please bear with me because I may not ask the question correctly and fresh out of college so this wasn't taught, and I'm a bit confused. I'm working with `dbt` and my models are being orchestrated by `Airflow DAGS`. I have a total of 240 models and of that 240, fifty-six go through a `reverse etl` process. I'd like to be able to build a couple of python classes that will do the following:

1. One dataclass to hold airflow generic variables.
2. A python Class that truncates fact and snapshots from models
3. An environment class that reads all the environment variables for all the regions
4. A Dag class python that will inheirit the attributes from the other classes to create multiple tags.

Essentially, I want to have one operator class that will loop through all the reverse etl python configuration files to create dags from them. I hope that makes sense.

I've referenced [Designing repeatable DAGS in Airflow (Part 1)](https://medium.com/cts-technologies/designing-repeatable-dags-in-airflow-part-1-db3a72a2307d)

But I'm having trouble understanding how to put it altogether. My configuration json file will have all the environments it will be deployed to when the dag is running. Is there sudo code that will help me with this? I don't wan't to go down a rabbit hole and create a bunch of configuration files for each dataset when there might be a better way. The sample code below is more or less the same for the the other 50 or so days. I'm trying to condense the code on this so we have one python file/module to run all of the datasets when they need to be ran on their schedules.

My environment variables file looks like:

```
{
  "environments":{
      "staging": {
           "bgq_proc_id_source": "groupaccount_staging",
           "bgq_project_id": "groupaccount_staging",
           "dbt_location_country: "US",
           "dbt_data_location": "US"
           "dbt_bgq_central_alias": "central",
           "bgq_schema_name": "stg_",
           "bgq_dataset_name": legacy"
      },
      "ops": {
           "bgq_proc_id_source": "groupaccount_staging",
           "bgq_project_id": "groupaccount_staging",
           "dbt_location_country: "US",
           "dbt_data_location": "US"
           "dbt_bgq_central_alias": "central",
           "bgq_schema_name": "ops_",
           "bgq_dataset_name": raw_legacy"
      }
}
```

Overview of general python dag files:

```
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.mysql_operator import MysqlOperator
from airflow.providers.mysql.hooks.mysql import MySqlHook
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.python import get_crrent_context
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
from utils.constants.schedule_interval import ScheduleInterval
from utils.operators.bigquery_to_mysql import BigQueryToMySqlOperatorSword
from utils.variables import (dag_default_args, get_json_variable_value, get_variaible,)
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql

# Want this to be a class by itself I think.
def check(is_inital_snapshot(mysql_hook, table_name, mpt_tbl_tak, non_mpt_tbl_tsk):
row_count = mysql_hook.get_pandas_df(
    f"select count(*) as num_rows from {table_name})
foce_snapshot = get_current_context()['dag_run'].conf.get('force_snapshot", False)
logging.info("%s has %s rows", table_name, row_count['num_rows'][0])


def define_dag(region: str):
    """Based on a region parameter, create a DAG for the region

    Args:
        region (str): Region (or environment) name. E.g.: "dev", "staging", "us", "eu"

    Returns:
        DAG: A dag object
    """
    BASE_DAG_ID = "client_bq_to_mysql"
    DAG_ID = f"default_name_{region}_{BASE_DAG_ID}"
    DATA_ENVIRONMENT = get_json_variable_value("environments", region)
    MYSQL_CONN_ID = f"mysql_connection_id"

    SNAPSHOT_SOURCE_TABLE_NAME = (
        f"{DATA_ENVIRONMENT['bgq_project_id']}.my_data_warehouse.fact_tbl_client_snapshot"
    )
    SUMMARY_SOURCE_TABLE_NAME = (
        f"{DATA_ENVIRONMENT['bgq_project_id']}.my_data_warehouse.fact_tbl_client_data"
    )


    SNAPSHOT_TARGET_TABLE_NAME = "client_data_aggregate"
    SNAPSHOT_TARGET_DATABASE = "client_dashboard"
    SNAPSHOT_TMP_TARGET_DATABASE = "integration_etl"
    SNAPSHOT_TARGET_TABLE_SCHEMA = {
        "my_schema_template": mysql.VARCHAR(36),
        
    }
    SNAPSHOT_SOURCE_SQL_QUERY = f"""
        SELECT
            *, 
            refreshed_at
        FROM {SNAPSHOT_SOURCE_TABLE_NAME} mp
    """
    SNAPSHOT_INSERT_QUERY = f"""
        REPLACE INTO {SNAPSHOT_TARGET_TABLE_NAME} (
        selected fields 
        )
        SELECT
            *
        FROM {SNAPSHOT_TMP_TARGET_DATABASE}.tmp_{SNAPSHOT_TARGET_TABLE_NAME} as aux
    """



    SUMMARY_TARGET_TABLE_NAME = "client_summary"
    SUMMARY_TARGET_DATABASE = "client_dashboard_feed"
    SUMMARY_TMP_TARGET_DATABASE = "marketing_integration_etl"
    SUMMARY_TARGET_TABLE_SCHEMA = {
        "myschema_here": mysql.VARCHAR(36)
    }
    SUMMARY_SOURCE_SQL_QUERY = f"""
        SELECT
           *
        FROM {SUMMARY_SOURCE_TABLE_NAME} mp
    """
    SUMMARY_INSERT_QUERY = f"""
        REPLACE INTO {SUMMARY_TARGET_TABLE_NAME}(
        query goes here
        )
        SELECT
            *
        FROM {SUMMARY_TMP_TARGET_DATABASE}.tmp_{SUMMARY_TARGET_TABLE_NAME} as aux
    """


    # If key exist in dictionary, return the value
    try:
        if BASE_DAG_ID in get_variable("inactive_dags"):
            return None
    except KeyError:
        print("Key not found. Proceeding...")

    with DAG(
        dag_id=DAG_ID,
        catchup=False,
        schedule_interval=ScheduleInterval.EVERY_DAY_8AM,
        max_active_runs=1,
        default_args=dag_default_args(
            start_date=datetime(2022, 6, 26),
            params={
                "incremental_days": 31,
            }
        ),
        tags=[region, "my_region", "data-name"],
        is_paused_upon_creation=True,
    ) as dag:
        summary_tmp_bq_to_mysql_snapshot = BigQueryToMySqlOperatorSword(
            task_id="summary_tmp_bq_to_mysql_snapshot",
            gcp_conn_id="my_gcp_connection",
            bq_table=SUMMARY_SOURCE_TABLE_NAME,
            database=SUMMARY_TMP_TARGET_DATABASE,
            mysql_conn_id=MYSQL_CONN_ID,
            sql=SUMMARY_SOURCE_SQL_QUERY,
            mysql_table="tmp_{}".format(SUMMARY_TARGET_TABLE_NAME),
            sql_limit=300000,
            schema_dtype=SUMMARY_TARGET_TABLE_SCHEMA,
            transfer_type="snapshot",
        )


        snapshot_tmp_bq_to_mysql_snapshot = BigQueryToMySqlOperatorSword(
            task_id="snapshot_tmp_bq_to_mysql_snapshot",
            gcp_conn_id="gcp_data_dbt_production_us",
            bq_table=SNAPSHOT_SOURCE_TABLE_NAME,
            database=SNAPSHOT_TMP_TARGET_DATABASE,
            mysql_conn_id=MYSQL_CONN_ID,
            sql=SNAPSHOT_SOURCE_SQL_QUERY,
            mysql_table="tmp_{}".format(SNAPSHOT_TARGET_TABLE_NAME),
            sql_limit=300000,
            schema_dtype=SNAPSHOT_TARGET_TABLE_SCHEMA,
            transfer_type="incremental",
            incremental_key="refreshed_at",
            incremental_days=31
        )

        summary_data_insert = MySqlOperator(
            task_id="summary_data_insert",
            database=SUMMARY_TARGET_DATABASE,
            sql=SUMMARY_INSERT_QUERY,
            mysql_conn_id=MYSQL_CONN_ID,
            trigger_rule=TriggerRule.NONE_FAILED
        )

        snapshot_data_insert = MySqlOperator(
            task_id="snapshot_data_insert",
            database=SNAPSHOT_TARGET_DATABASE,
            sql=SNAPSHOT_INSERT_QUERY,
            mysql_conn_id=MYSQL_CONN_ID,
            trigger_rule=TriggerRule.NONE_FAILED
        )


    return dag


# Get all regions that must be created in the Airflow environment
dag_regions = get_json_variable_value("environments")

# Create a DAG for each region (1 or more)
for dag_region in dag_regions:
    globals()[f"{dag_region}_dbt_run_legacy"] = define_dag(dag_region)
```